Extrude mesh based on proximity to faces
I am learning Geo Nodes and trying to understand this:
Why is the extrusion uniform and not based on the empty controller's position and different faces?
I expected to see that the greater the distance, the more extrusion, and vice versa.

File


Geometry proximity is used to get distance from Mesh to Mesh, for proximity between mesh and point in space (like empty position) simple vector distance should be used.

(Using Blender 3.6.12)
I understand you are looking for this:

The Extrude Mesh node is set in Face domain. Consequently, when triggering the Distance vector math node, it is requiring through the Position node the coordinates of each face centre of its input Mesh. The Object Info node is returning the coordinates of the Empty origin, measured from the origin of the object carrying the GeometryNodes modifier, because its Transform Space property is set to Relative. So the Distance node is computing the relative distance between each individual face centre and the Empty origin.

Pretty sure this is because Geometry Proximity requires actual geometry to detect proximity to.
You can achieve what you're looking for with a node setup like this.

Results:


Just saw you want it to be greater extrusion distance for greater distance to the object, then you would just skip the "Flip so it's 1-0" node. Then that should work exact as you want.
